# Create a new table on the database and save parameters from a contact form

Tags: database, mysql

I have a wordpress function in functions.php which gets parameters from a form I made and gets parameters like IP addresses and UTM tags (from the URL) and sends them to me by email.

I want to get all these parameters I send and store them in a new table on my WP database.

How can I do such thing?

I researched it and found a lot of plugins that can do that for me (Which I really don't want to use external plugins). 
and I still want to keep wordpress security and not use a "flat" code of my own.

How do I plan this? Is this even possible?

Comment: As your question is, it is so board that it can not be answered here easily. That being said, using plugins is a very good option if the plugin is well coded and does exactly what you want, specially if you don't know how to do it at your own.

Comment: I want to learn doing this by myself.. what should I start researching more specifically ?

Comment: You could start reading these entries in Wordpress documentation: [Creating Tables with Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) and [wpdb class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb). You could also be interested in more general readings about database field types to correctly define and optimize your database table, but I can not find a good but basic tutorial and I'm not a database expert, sorry.

Comment: for the idea to create a new table, I advice you to avoid this and to use a custom post type for storing data : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Comment: @mmm I'm not sure what that even mean, but I'll right it down as a note.

Comment: @mmm post types are not a solution for every data type/structure. Custom tables can be better for a lot of situations; although I've never used custom tables in WordPress, I've seen a lot of situations where the use of custom tables are totally justified.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest for you some ideas :

1. Before run functions from you make, you register table database store ( Example WP_IP and WP_UTM )
2. After create 2 table that, you run function of you
3. You need read on Codex some resource on WP working with parameters :

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb
https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins